# In secondary dimension i still see custom variables appearing

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

We have recently implemented a new instance of UA and GA4. With this implementation we have passed a few of our custom dimensions via custommap function in the gTag.js

```
gtag('config', 'GA_XXXXXXXX', {'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'product_id'}
```

After that we did set up custom dimensions inside the custom dimension in Google Analytics Admin

`Admin > Property > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions > +New Custom Dimension`

Now when we check our instance in the secondary dimensions we are able to see

> **Custom Dimensions** that did set in Google Analytics Admin - but no data is being pushed in them.
>
> > No data is being pushed in these custom dimensions.
> >
> > > what would be the best way to debug this solution

> We see another tab **Custom Variables** - which have values like **custom variable 11** etc.
>
> > Data is coming in them.
> >
> > > What would be the best way to figure out the corresponding custom variable key value pair mapping from the google dev tools?

Comment: Did your `gtag` miss a close bracket `)`?

Comment: what do you mean by ```gtag``` missing a close bracket?

Comment: Don't you see there is a missing bracket at the end of your codes? Your browser should report that as well.

Comment: @Raptor, Can you kindly let me know how can i find via browser. sorry for asking noobish questions!

Comment: when checked via omnibug i do see the below dimensions popping up

Comment: i do see a few custom dimensions popping up but i still custom variables in passing. Also, when we did the implementation via the  data layer we didnt build custom dimensions in the GA at that moment. we built them after sometime, can those variable because of the gap?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, it's in browser menu > More Tools > Developer Tools, or simply right click on the page and select "Inspect"

Comment: i am not sure how to check the data layer via dev tools, i can see the network and collect payload to see whats coming in.